# Unable to debug android application

Tags: android, debugging

I need to debug my application to look for content in variables and so on. I usually do this on my phone with usb debugging driver and eclipse. But my app won't automatically start on the phone any longer. The console in Eclipse only shows this:

```
[2012-03-29 17:18:56 - AppName] Performing sync
[2012-03-29 17:18:58 - AppName] Uploading AppName.apk onto device '80A354043047206372'
[2012-03-29 17:18:58 - AppName] Installing AppName.apk...
[2012-03-29 17:19:01 - AppName] Success!
[2012-03-29 17:19:01 - AppName] \AppName\bin\AppName.apk installed on device
[2012-03-29 17:19:01 - AppName] Done!
```

Now I have to start my app manually, and therefore I can't debug the app.

Any suggestions to this problem?

Comment: Have you remove the `android.intent.action.MAIN` or `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` in your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to config your `Run configuration` in the eclipse like below showing picture, look at your `Launch Action`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, add `andrdoid:debuggable="true"`
And launch your app in debugging mode.

I also think that you don't have any launcher activity. Make sure you have an activity with LAUNCHER CATERGORY and ACTION MAIN.

Comment: Under which tag should I put the statement? Under the application tag?

Comment: C'mon man get sporty. Dig it out. Even if you google that line, you'll come to know where to put it. But good practice is trial and error.